# What is the behaviour of HttpClient with multiple A records?

Tags: .net

If I have a DNS A record resolving to two IP Addresses, what is the behavior of the System.Net.Http.HttpClient when connecting to the domain?

For example:

- Curl tries the first IP address, if it fails to open a connection it
  tries the second.
- Python's request library tries both IP Addresses, first to get a
  connection wins (and I assumed the other is closed).
- NodeJS appears to try the first one, if it doesn't work, too bad for
  you.

I can't seem to find the documentation of what dotnets HttpClient does. It would be great to know that I can have two machines in the A record, and if one has issues, clients that  get connection errors will try again, and ultimately get the other IP.

My worry is that the client may get a connection error, then retry only that ip address, which means they will be permanently errored until they are either restarted, or the first machine is fixed.